# Getting packages for GO language

Tags: go, gogs

The below command is taking ages with no output or anything, is there an alternative way to download packages for go language.? I am new to golang.

```
 go get -u github.com/gogits/gogs/
```

PS: my net connection is not that slow, downloading through git takes around 1 min, but i can't individually do that for all dependencies.

Edit 1: Small packages like `go get github.com/tools/godep` downloads and install flawlessly,  i have the problem only with github.com/gogits/gogs/ . Its stuck there for an hour.  Even a download progress  would have been helpful.

Comment: would the down votes care to comment ?

Comment: What version of `git` do you have?

Comment: @JimB git version 1.9.1

Comment: ***go get*** command is working but its terribly slow for packages that have lots of dependencies. the **-v** flag helped me to get a verbose output of what is happening.

Answer (score 2):

***go get*** command is working but its terribly slow for packages that have lots of dependencies. the **-v** flag(not in doc) helped me to get a verbose output of what is happening.

Took almost an hour to finish. Culprit might possibly be github or my ISP.
Verbose output should had made default by the developers.

*sorry for my English.

Answer (score -1):

You can use GoDep which is a powerful Go dependency manager: https://github.com/tools/godep

GoDep also helps you to have a predictable build since it freezes dependencies in your app
Very easy to get started, just follow instruction on its Github page.

Comment: I will give a try and update here, thanks for the answer.

Comment: 'godep get  github.com/gogits/gogs'  is also stuck  indefinitely . I think it has to do with the size of package.

Comment: Hmmm, is your environment setup correctly? Seems you have some sort of configuration issues. (just a guess). Just create a fresh VM, install Go and give it another try please.